# How to update AngularJS directive when URL is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set active tab style with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295983/set-active-tab-style-with-angularjs)

I'm using AngularJS and trying to add a "current" class to my menu whenever that tab's content is being displayed. This is what I have so far, and it works fine when loading the page:

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#/one" class="highlighttab">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/two" class="highlighttab">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
myModule.directive('highlighttab', function($location) {
    var currentPath = "#" + $location.path();

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var href = element.attr("href");
            if (currentPath == href)
            {
                element.addClass("current");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This will add the 'current' class to the correct `<a>` tag when the page url is `#/one` or `/#two`

The problem is if I click the second tab, the class does not get added to it. I imagine I need some way to get the code inside the directive to be re-run when the URL changes. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295983

Comment: kfis' answer uses a directive, so probably exactly what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using kfis's code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631214/1684860 in the comments, I have this working now using $scope.watch on location.path() .

```
myModule.directive('highlighttab', ['$location', function(location) {

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var elementPath = $attrs.href.substring(1);
            $scope.$location = location;
            $scope.$watch('$location.path()', function(locationPath) {
                (elementPath === locationPath) ? $element.addClass("current") : $element.removeClass("current");
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using ngView/routeProvider you probably need to listen for a route change event, perhaps $routeChangeSuccess [1](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route).

e.g. in your link function:

```
scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, current, previous) {
    if (current == href) {
      element.addClass("current");
    }
    else {
      element.removeClass("current");
    }
});
```

Not tested so might need tinkering e.g. for presence/absence of '#'.  I expect your `currentPath` variable is only being evaluated once, so you might want to rework that into the link function so its effective scope is clearer.

[1](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route]

Comment: +1 Interesting idea thanks, I hadn't thought of that.