# Directive Doesn't Update Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Js:

```
myApp.directive('locationClass', function ($location) {

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var currentLocation = $location.path();

            var formatCurrentLocation = currentLocation.replace(/\//g, " ");

            //console.log(currentLocation);
            element.addClass(formatCurrentLocation);
    }

    }

});
```

**Html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="headerCtrl as header" location-class>
```

it works corrrectly , but when pages load,  it updated , when i change steps the value does not update .

**Url Example**: `CounterForm/InstallCounter` to `CounterForm/CounterEquipment`

I'm using `Ui-router` .
  Any Idea ?
Thanks

Comment: when should it update? when a scope property changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link function is called only once when the directive gets rendered.

This means that when your html was rendered for the first time, then only, the function was called. And so it did the work. When the url changes, you need listeners to update according to the changes.

It won't have live connections to the URL.

You need to create a listener on **$locationChangeSuccess** event in the link function. That should do your work.

Check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for documentation. Search for this function there.
Then whenever you change your url, it will be called and the changes will be done. Your directive becomes like:

```
myApp.directive('locationClass', function ($location, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                var currentLocation = $location.path();

                var formatCurrentLocation = currentLocation.replace(/\//g, " ");

                //console.log(currentLocation);
                element.addClass(formatCurrentLocation);
            });

    }
}
```

**UPDATE for the purpose of toggling classes:**

You use a scope variable instead. We can just have a variable to store the class and put the variable on the html. Check the **locationClass** variable in the html.

So your html will be like :

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="headerCtrl as header" location-class class="{{locationClass}}">
```

and your directive, we modify as :

```
myApp.directive('locationClass', function ($location, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                var currentLocation = $location.path();

                var formatCurrentLocation = currentLocation.replace(/\//g, " ");
                scope.locationClass = formatCurrentLocation;

            });

    }
}
```

So now whenever you change  your location, when the change is successful, the variable will be updated on the class attribute and your html will have new class. You don't need to remove the old class manually.

I think this will solve the problem and also it is a better way of doing stuff. We don't want to handle DOM directly unless necessary in AngularJS. If variable can do that, we do it.

**UPDATE 2:(if you want to use watch)**:

We can keep a watch on location.path() and use that  also to track the classname.

```
myApp.directive('locationClass', function ($location, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            scope.$watch('$location.path()', function(currentLocation) {

                var formatCurrentLocation = currentLocation.replace(/\//g, " ");
                scope.locationClass = formatCurrentLocation;
            });

    }
}
```

But still I would recommend that you go for the listener on location change success.
The reason being that the watch is heavy and will be triggered everytime the scope becomes dirty(means almost everytime if the scope is on body) whereas the event listener will call the function only when the url gets changed. You can put a console inside the function to check and verify this.

Comment: the problem is , the new classes won't replace with old one, and jus add classes in html

Comment: modified it. Please check.

Comment: thanks for your useful tips , but the class is not working, also i tried ng-class

Comment: It works for me. The problem was $scope was not defined in the directive. Correcting that. You must also be getting the same error.

Comment: Remove $ from scope and check again

Comment: yesssss, that's true, can i ask you something else ? can you tell me how to solve this with $ watch ? please see the answer below

Comment: thanks a million , the way you wrote with $watch is working once at a time, but i got the idea

Answer (score 2):

you have to watch your scope variable for change

```
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
     name: '='
   },
   link: function($scope) {
     $scope.$watch('name', function() {
        // all the code here...
     });
   }
};
```

As per your example i think it will work

```
 scope.$watch('data', function(){ // replace data with variable on which you have to watch change
                var currentLocation = $location.path();
                var formatCurrentLocation = currentLocation.replace(/\//g, " ");
                element.addClass(formatCurrentLocation);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            });
```

Comment: 1+ thanks , what's that ? $compile(element.contents())(scope);

Comment: you can use compile to link scope and the template together. if you have any variable which is present in your template or in html then to link scope of that variable we can use compile

Comment: The compilation is a process of walking the DOM tree and matching DOM elements to directives.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: and one more question , how can i use data in your $watch ?

Comment: data is just an example you have to use variable in which you want to watch change

Comment: see this angular life cycle example http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html then you know how angular works

Comment: would you please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669674/how-to-update-angularjs-directive-when-url-is-changed
the answer watch only $Location

Comment: The watch is correct but @keval, you cannot keep compiling the whole directive. If it is a directive at some small element levet it makes total sense, but when you keep on compiling the whole body(see the directive position) on every location change, it is not recommended. Why? because, it will basically re-render all the elements which are static and have nothing to do with location changes and makes the application uncessarily heavy.