# How to set li tag to active by looping through json data?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image]

I currently have a json file that has page title and content data.

Like so :

```
[
  {
  "title":"About",
  "content":"About me . . . . . . "
  },
  {
  "title":"Contact",
  "content":"Reach me . . . ." 
  },
  {
  "title":"Create a Post",
  "content": "What's on your mind?"
  }
]
```

The json data is attached to an angular controller.

`.controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
        $http.get('../../../data/pages.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.page = data[$routeParams.id];
        });
    }])`

This information is attached to the dom view with angular js and ng-repeat.
I am looping `ng-repeat="page in pages"` and so far I see the About, Contact, and Create Post page successfully. I can even click on the li tag and successfully transfer to the correct page.

However my problem is that the li tag never registers with an **active** class.

Here is my code snippet.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li ng-class="{'active': 1}" ng-repeat="page in pages"><a href="#/page/{{pages.indexOf(page)}}">{{page.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I set the li tag to active with this set up?

Comment: duplicate question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295983/set-active-tab-style-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you're using `page.title` and `page.content` somewhere in the view to actually show the title and content of the page.

Having those two available means that you could set do something like
`<li ng-class="{'active': page.title === currentPage.title}" ng-repeat="currentPage in pages"><a href="#/page/{{pages.indexOf(currentPage)}}">{{currentPage.title}}</a></li>`

If you post the entire view and controller this would be easier to diagnose though

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. You are right I am missing some content & I do have a page.content and page.title. However I seemed to figure out what the problem was. Because I am using bootstrap-material-design I was able to fix highlighting of the active links with this script in the dom page        ```<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $.material.init();
  }); 
</script> ``` Thank for your help.