# AngularJS sidebar link to stay active when clicked

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, plunker

I am creating a sidebar based off of this one

http://plnkr.co/edit/xzcjStdvmkI2rpfMzLjI?p=preview found from [this tutorial](http://devartisans.com/articles/sidebar-navigation-using-angular)

However I want to keep the selection active once the link is clicked. I've tried adding data-toggle, but that seems to work for nav-pills instead of navbar. I also found an is-active-nav directive that I've attempted to implement:

```
angular.module('sidebarmodule')
    .directive('isActiveNav', ['$location', function ($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.location = $location;
            scope.$watch('location.path()', function (currentPath) {
                if ('/#' + currentPath === element[0].attributes['href'].nodeValue) {
                    element.parent().addClass('active');
                } else {
                    element.parent().removeClass('active');
                }
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

That I call in the sidebar template like so:

```
<li> <a is-active-nav href="#">Link1</a> </li>
```

Another approach I tried is in my controller adding   `$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { return viewLocation === $location.path(); };` and then adding to the template: `<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/importinvoice')}"><a href="#/firstlink">First Link</a></li>`

However, nothing I do will keep the sidebar elements highlighted after navigating to that page. I am trying to keep out of jQuery as I want it to be an AngularJS solution only.

I tried most of the solutions from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592472/how-to-highlight-a-current-menu-item) but can't get any of them to work on the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `tab` property in `$scope`, assign it a tab identifier and then use `ng-class="{'active': tab==='tab1'}"`

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I tried this also. I created ng-class="{ active: isActive('/firstlink')}" and created a function   $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { return viewLocation === $location.path(); }; based off of other stackflow answers. this did not work.

Comment: Here is the stackoverflow link with what you are suggesting, for those looking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295983/set-active-tab-style-with-angularjs I just can't get it to work with the plunker

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
     <div class="sidebar" sidebar-directive="state" ng-init="item=-1">
        <a href="#" id="navigation-toggle" ng-click="toggleState()">Navigation</a>
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#" ng-click="item=0" ng-class="{'active':item==0}">Link1</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#"ng-click="item=1" ng-class="{'active':item==1}">Link2</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#" ng-click="item=2" ng-class="{'active':item==2}">Link3</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#" ng-click="item=3" ng-class="{'active':item==3}">Link4</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#" ng-click="item=4" ng-class="{'active':item==4}">Link4</a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

see link : http://plnkr.co/edit/xzcjStdvmkI2rpfMzLjI?p=preview

Comment: I don't think you attached the correct Plunker but I'll attempt this method

Comment: It doesn't work in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bUWo4RgpxhHYvyTo4Wol?p=preview

Comment: you also need to add **.active** class in **style.css** like:  .active{
               background-color : #222!important;
            }