# setting active menu in angular js with routing

Tags: angularjs

Newbie in `angularjs`. Trying to learn some new stuffs.

I have a simple page and when the user navigates to different page I need to set `active` class on respective `li` of the `menuitem`. Below is the way I have added routes.

```
angular.module('home', ["ngRoute"]).
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', { templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: "homeController", activetab: "home" }).
        when('/about', { templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', activetab: "about" }).
        when('/gallery', { templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html', activetab: "gallery" }).
        when('/contact', { templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html', activetab: "contact" }).
        when('/services', { templateUrl: 'partials/services.html', activetab: "services" }).
        when('/house', { templateUrl: 'partials/house.html', activetab: "house" }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home', templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', activetab: "home" });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).controller("homeController", function ($scope, $http, $route) {
    $scope.$route = $route;
});
```

And I will have only `homecontroller` which is binded only when user visits home page. Other pages will have only static data.

I've added `ng-app` to my `html` as below:

```
<html ng-app="home">
```

Below is how I've tried to add `active` class to `li`.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li ng-class="{'active': $route.current.activetab == 'home'}"><a href="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
     <li ng-class="{'active': $route.current.activetab == 'about'}"><a href="about">About</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{'active': $route.current.activetab == 'services'}"><a href="services">Services</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{'active': $route.current.activetab == 'house'}"><a href="house">The house</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{'active': $route.current.activetab == 'gallery'}"><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{'active': $route.current.activetab == 'contact'}"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I had no luck in completing this. Even though navigation happens the active class does not gets added. I've followed **[answer mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586203/2065039)**. Please let me know how else I can achieve this or what is my mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc3j528y/) example I made, the reason it does not work is after you switch state, you do not have access to the `$route`. the `$route` is only accessible in your `homecontroller`'s `$scope`, which I assume only applying to your home page.

Comment: Yes.. that was the problem. I followed a different approach then.. I bound a controller to index page.. now it works fine and urs too.. Thanks much..