# AngularJS - Update controller var on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

I'm pretty much a newbie in the AngularJS world.
This is my problem. I would like to update the selected tab based on the url, so that the selected tab changes when the url changes.

This is my js:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
      $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {
          templateUrl: '/views/pages/page1.html',
          controller: "TabController",
          tab: 1
        })
         .when('/page2', {
          templateUrl: '/views/pages/page2.html',
          controller: "TabController",
          tab: 2
        })
        .otherwise({
          template: "Error 404"
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
    });

    //Tabs
    app.controller("TabController", function($scope, $route){
      $scope.activeTab = 0;

      if(typeof $route.current != "undefined"){
        setTimeout(function(){$scope.activeTab = $route.current.activeTab; console.log($scope.activeTab);},100);
      }
    });
```

And this is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="TabController">
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <section class="section section--xs">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="tab__single" ng-class="{active: activeTab === 1}">
          <a href="/page1" class="tab__single__name">Page 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab__single" ng-class="{active: activeTab === 2}">
          <a href="/page2" class="tab__single__name">Page 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- ./tabs -->

  <!-- Content -->
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <!-- ./content -->
</div>
```

I try and if I log the tab value, it actually updates, because it logs the correct value, but then the new tab doesn't get selected. Any suggestions?

Comment: this may [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295983/set-active-tab-style-with-angularjs)

Comment: @ricky I tried the very first solution, but it doesn't update anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function to search in your url parameters:

```
$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
    return viewLocation === $location.path();
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
        <div class="tab__single" ng-class="{active: isActive('page1')}">
          <a href="/page1" class="tab__single__name">Page 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab__single" ng-class="{active: isActive('page2')}">
          <a href="/page2" class="tab__single__name">Page 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to work pretty well!