# ng-class in AngularJS about pagination in node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pagination

i am doing a pagination, now i have to do that, if i am currently on page my button must change color.

I have done so far:

```
<span ng-repeat="page in pagination(pages) track by $index">
  <button ng-class="{ changecolour: isActive(page) }" ng-click='loadProducts($index+1, pageSize)' class="btn btn-default">{{$index+1}}</button>
</span>
```

controller

```
$scope.isActive = function (page) {
  return page == page;
};
```

I know that it is wrong, can someone tell me how to do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set active tab style with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295983/set-active-tab-style-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `$scope.page` value inside the function `loadProducts($index+1, pageSize)` whenever you click the button. Let's say your function be like this

```
$scope.loadProducts = function(index, pageSize){
    //determine the page 
    $scope.page = index;
}
```

And use `ng-class` as

```
ng-class="{ changecolour: isActive($index+1) }"
```

Now your `isActive` function will be

```
$scope.isActive = function(page){
   return $scope.page === page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like this If you have page = page number.

```
ng-class="{active: page == currentPage}"
```